# Issue connecting to Mariadb docker container from .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to a locally hosted MariaDB Docker container.
I am using this docker compose setup:

```
mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: conciergedb
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKERPATH}/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mariainit:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.3
```

I managed to connect via mysql cli on ubuntu wsl using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u brian -p` and using MySQLWorkbench using the following configuration:

```
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306
Username: brian
Default Schema: conciergedb
```

Now, back to .NET (using MySql.Data.MySqlClient), I am using this connection string:

```
server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user id=brian;password=<PASS>;database=conciergedb;ConnectionTimeout=60;
```

This throws this error on conn.Open():

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'
```

If I do not close the connection, the Docker log throws this on debug exit:

```
[Warning] Aborted connection # to db: 'conciergedb' user: 'brian' host: '10.5.0.1' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

So this tells me that *something* is going through but not acknowledged. Any ideas to what I can try?

P.S. I also tried connecting to 10.5.0.3 out of desperation to no avail.

Comment: Do you have to use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`? If not then try to use the `MySqlConnector` library instead. I got it working with that library. If this would be fine for you I could also post my working code as an answer then.

Comment: Is your application also running inside a container?

Comment: I managed to connect by switching to MySqlConnector and switching the startup mode from Docker to https. For now, I am going to use the https until I fully incorporate the app inside my docker-compose script. Why it wouldn't connect when ran in Docker mode is beyond me right now but I will figure it out and update this thread.

Comment: "Why it wouldn't connect when ran in Docker mode is beyond me right now" - this is because 127.0.0.1 when running in Docker is not the same as 127.0.0.1 when running on the host machine. Try using `host.docker.internal` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming your app is also running in a container within the same Docker network as MariaDb. In which case the problem is your connection string. The name of the container running MariaDb is;

```
mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
```

Therefore your database connection string is:

```
server=mariadb;port=3306;user id=
```